# How can I compare the speed of two algorithms implemented in verilog HDL without using FPGA?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, xilinx, vivado, hdl

I have implemented two 32 bit multiplier algorithms (Booth and Karatsuba) in verilog HDL. I wanted to make a comparison of the time taken by both algorithms to multiply same numbers. How can I do that without using an FPGA in Xilinx Vivado?

Comment: Won't this vary depending upon the logic cells and their architecture, when discussing FPGA, or by whatever FAB technology and rules are involved, for ASIC? (Also, I cannot imagine the automated floorplanner doing as well as you might, by hand, if you work at it. Plus, I've seen creativity do wonders, as well. I think you need to define some specific goals to help shape your methodology in making comparisons before starting down the path.)

Comment: The thing that struck Kolmogorov was not that you can get what's usually achieved summing aligned results of four multiplications using three products/multiplications + change. It was that applying this *recursively* needs a number of operations *growing significantly slower* than the square of input size. *Time* being very much dependent on parallelism, I suggest the thing to compare is not delay, but some measure of circuit *size*. And a fair implementation for fixed operand size should do at least two levels.

Comment: You can synthesise (and P&R) both, and observe the timing analysis report. Then, to be sure, you can ratchet up the timing constraints until the tools fail to provide a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no speed without an implementation – that just makes no sense. Only the hardware you have at hand defines which kind of logic components (muxes, LUTs, adders…) you have, how they can be connected, and how their relative speeds and capabilities are.

So, the implementation of your algorithm in logic hardware depends on your choice of FPGA – and thus the speed. You will *have* to choose an FPGA to *synthesize* for that target.

The synthesizer then will actually tell you which clock rate you can maximally attain using your design as is; and you, knowing how much result you get "per clock cycle" can infer speed from that.